# Join Linq column with minimum value column

Tags: linq

I have to join outer table column with inner table minimum value column

Here is my sql query:

```
    SELECT        O.Id, O.Name, O.Designation  
                         FROM            TableA AS O INNER JOIN  
                                     (SELECT        MIN(SrNo) AS A_SNo, Id  
                                                         FROM            TableA 
                                                         WHERE        (Active = 1)  
                                                         GROUP BY Id) AS I ON O.Id = I.Id AND O.SrNo = I.A_SNo AND O.Active = 1
```

I have tried this:

```
      from tres in TableA join O in
     (from tresp in TableA 
                                             where tresp.Active == true                                    
                                             group tresp by new { tresp.Id } into G
                                             select new { Id = G.Key.Id, A_Sno =(int?)G.Min(X=>X.SrNo)}
                                            ) on new {tres.Id,a=(int?)tres.SrNo } equals new {O.Id,a=O.A_Sno } into tresss

                                                where (tres.Active==true)
                                        select new { tres.Id, tres.Name, tres.Designation }
```

in sql query I'm not getting duplicate rows but when i tried this in linq getting duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from tres in TableA join O in
     (from tresp in TableA 
      where tresp.Active == true                                    
      group tresp by new { tresp.Id } into G
      select new { Id = G.Key.Id, A_Sno =(int?)G.Min(X=>X.SrNo)}
     ) on new {tres.Id,a=(int?)tres.SrNo } equals new {O.Id,a=O.A_Sno } 
      where (tres.Active==true)
      select new {tres.Id,tres.Name,tres.Designation} into tresss
      select new { tresss.Id, tresss.Name, tresss.Designation }
```